# Apply default ControlTemplate to only one Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I have modified the ControlTemplate for ComboBoxEdit like this (in App.xaml):

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomComboBoxEditTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ButtonEdit}">
           ...
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dxe:ComboBoxEdit}">
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CustomComboBoxEditTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

For 1 Control in I need the original. How can I set the original template for only 1 control?

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="PART_Editor" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
   Template="What can I write here?">
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the Style property to `{x:Null}` to use the default style:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Name="PART_Editor" ItemsSource="{Binding ...}" Style="{x:Null}" />
```

Of course this assumes that the control actually has a default style.